# Xamarin Forms on iOS How To Set Screen Orientation for Page?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

So the title says it all. Im concerned at this point with iOS. I have tried to sue a custom renderer for my base page "LandscapeContentPage" which would hopefully force it to be rendered as landscape. I have been unsuccessful.

I attempted to use a hack I found where in ViewDidAppear you present a "fake" UIViewController that overrides the GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations to only return Landscape. This sort of works. The meat looks like this:

```
var c = new LandscapeViewController();
c.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;

await PresentViewControllerAsync(c, false);
await DismissViewControllerAsync(false);
```

If I set a breakpoint at the Dismiss line I can see in the simulator that the view did change to landscape, the simulator window actually rotates on its own. When I continue either an error is thrown about view transitions or the ViewDidAppear fires again and the original page is displayed in portrait orientation.

So, I'm more or less lost at this point. I have tried so many different things and had zero success. I can't figure out why there isn't an out of the box mechanism for this. Such an expensive toolset/framework seems incomplete without orientation handling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I used a dependency service for this.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

### Interface

```
public interface IOrientationHandler
{
    void ForceLandscape();

    void ForcePortrait();
}
```

### Calling the interface from Forms

```
DependencyService.Get<IOrientationHandler>().ForceLandscape();
```

### IOS Implementation

```
public class OrientationHandlerImplementation : IOrientationHandler
    {
        public void ForceLandscape()
        {
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));
        }

        public void ForcePortrait()
        {
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
        }
    }
```

### Android Implementation

```
public class OrientationHandler : BaseDependencyImplementation, IOrientationHandler
{
    public void ForceLandscape()
    {
        GetActivity().RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    }

    public void ForcePortrait()
    {
        GetActivity().RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

Edit - Added Base Dependency Implementation as per request

### BaseDependency Implementation

```
 public class BaseDependencyImplementation : Object
    {
        public Activity GetActivity()
        {
            var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
            return activity;
        }
    }
```

If you want to set orientation for the whole app it can be done in the app settings / manifest file.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will try it out. And good timing too because I am just starting a new forms project that could use this kind of control.

Comment: Great stuff its my pleasure, let me know if you run into any issues,

Comment: what is BaseDependencyImplementation?

Comment: My mistake sorry for the oversight it is an additional Interface that I inherit from that gets the Activity context as you need to know which activity to perform the orientation on. I have added this as an edit to my answer

Comment: Tried this today and I was still able to go into landscape mode in iOS.

Answer (score 10):

The approach from Chad Bonthuys works like a charms. I've got two litte additions.

Android: If you rotate and leave the view, the other views now will be in the requested orientation as well. Just call

```
GetActivity().RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Unspecified;
```

on leaving. That will allow other views to rotate again.

iOS: The view will be rotated, but the user is still able to rotate it back. You can lock it if you override the

> GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()

on

> AppDelegate.cs

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations (UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)
{
    if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current == null || Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage == null)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
    }

    var mainPage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;

    if (mainPage is YOUR_VIEW||
            (mainPage is NavigationPage && ((NavigationPage)mainPage).CurrentPage is YOUR_VIEW) ||
            (mainPage.Navigation != null && mainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault () is YOUR_VIEW))
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
}
```

Just replace **YOUR_VIEW** with your ContentPage you want to lock

Comment: This is amazing - after a tremendous amount of searching, and experimenting, this is the only way I have found to be able to use an ImagePicker in an app that's supposed to be landscape only!

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works with out dependency service.

Suppose if we want to have three pages and for second page only we need to have landscape orientation, below code is working for me.

Add below method to AppDelegate.cs

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)
        {
            if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current == null || Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage == null)
            {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
            }

            var mainPage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;

            if (mainPage is SecondPage ||
                    (mainPage is NavigationPage && ((NavigationPage)mainPage).CurrentPage is SecondPage) ||
                    (mainPage.Navigation != null && mainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault() is SecondPage))
            {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
            }

            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }
```

Add a custom renderer to change the orientation.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MainPagePageRenderer))]
namespace App2.iOS
{
    public class MainPagePageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(NSNumber.FromNInt((int)(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)), new NSString("orientation"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we have three pages MainPage, SecondPage and ThirdPage in the app and we are trying to fix landscape orientation to SecondPage. We need to create a custom renderer for MainPage since we need to change the orientation when going to SecondPage. We fix the orientation in AppDelegate for SecondPage so it won't change the orientation even if we rotate the phone.

Now, the portrait orientation is locked for MainPage and ThirdPage and the landscape for SecondPage.

We may need to create as many as custom renderers for each page to fix orientation.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to put that code in `ViewWillAppear` of SecondPage, instead of in `ViewWillDisappear` of ThirdPage?  That seems more straightforward, as it is SecondPage that you are controlling the behavior of.  Is there some benefit to the way you did it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't write, if you only want to force the landscape-orientation for ONE page or for the whole app?
I think you know already, that you can force the orientation for the whole app in the project-settings (e.g. only landscape-orientation)?

Comment: Yes, thats why the title is says "for Page". So yeah it is for a single page not the entire app. Seems hard to believe that nobody else has a requirement for this in their apps.

Comment: I also have this requirement:-) I want to show a specific search-page on phones (only) in portrait-orientation (as it is not servable on a phone in landscape). So I have placed a "wish" to Jason to implement a new property to the page-object that allows to set the orientation for a single page. But... there is a long  time until Christmas... :-)

Comment: @Johan I haven't found one yet. Ive pretty much shelved that part of my project for now anyway. Im leaning toward not using XF for it and just doing a traditional Xamarin app because I need more control over the UI.