# How to rotate page in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

There are some pages in the App,Some pages are portrait,but some pages are landscape.
If using android native code,i can do it like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity1"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

But how to define different screen orientation in xamarin.forms

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057972/xamarin-forms-on-ios-how-to-set-screen-orientation-for-page

Comment: You're right to do so :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Achieve this making a Dependency

Make an interface in your Main Forms Project:

```
namespace Example
{
    public interface IOrientationHandler
    {
        void ForceLandscape();
        void ForcePortrait();
    }
}
```

**Call it like:**

```
DependencyService.Get<IOrientationHandler>().ForceLandscape();
DependencyService.Get<IOrientationHandler>().ForcePortrait();
```

**Android**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(OrientationHandler))]
namespace Example
{
    public class OrientationHandler : IOrientationHandler
    {
        public void ForceLandscape()
        {
            ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
        }

        public void ForcePortrait()
        {
            ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(OrientationHandlerImplementation))]
namespace Example
{
    public class OrientationHandlerImplementation : IOrientationHandler
    {
        public void ForceLandscape()
        {
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));
        }

        public void ForcePortrait()
        {
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way to undo this afterwards? Like turn it back to setting orientation based on the actual device orientation?

Comment: OnAppearing method you can use this DependencyService.Get<IOrientationHandler>().ForceLandscape();

OnDisappearing method use this
DependencyService.Get<IOrientationHandler>().ForcePortrait();